# syntax error, unexpected T_STRING php

Tags: php

It throws me a syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, and I don't see anything wrong with it.

```
<div id="main">
<div id="wrap">
    <?php 
        require("top.php"); 
        $archpreg=fopen("p.txt", 'a+');
        $archresp=fopen("r.txt", 'a+');
        $preg=fread($archpreg,filesize("p.txt"));
        $resp=fread($archresp,filesize("r.txt));
        fclose($archpreg); fclose($archresp);
        $listapreg= explode('###12', $preg); $listar= explode('###12', $resp); 
        for ($c=9; $c>=0; --$c){
            $p=array_pop($listapreg);
            $pp= explode ('###11',$p);
            $nombre= $pp[1];
            $apellido=$pp[2];
            $foto= base64_decode ($pp[3]);
            $id=$pp[0];
            $pregunta= $pp[5];
            $titulo= $pp[4];
            for ($i=0; $i<count($listar); ++$i){
                $r=$array_pop($listar);
                $rr=explode ('###11',$r);
                #if($rr[0]==$id){
                #   $nombre2=$rr[1];
                #   $apellido2=$rr[2];
                #   $respuesta=$rr[3];  
                #} ?>
                <div>
                    <h4><?php echo $titulo?></h4>
                    <h5>Escrita por: <?php echo $nombre.' '.$apellido; >?> </h5>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $pregunta ?>
                        <form method="get" action= "iresp.php">
                            <input type="submit" value="Responder!" id="responder"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="aaa" />
                        </form>
                    </p> 
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $respuesta ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
        <?php }
        } ?>


</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the actual error message? That may give some indication of what line is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The line `$resp=fread($archresp,filesize("r.txt));` is missing a ", it should be `$resp=fread($archresp,filesize("r.txt"));` or better yet `$resp=fread($archresp,filesize('r.txt'));` since there is no variable substitution in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$resp=fread($archresp,filesize("r.txt));
```

You have missed **"** sign ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some `"` in this line: `$resp=fread($archresp,filesize("r.txt));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$resp=fread($archresp,filesize("r.txt));
```

There is a missing `"`. You should use an editor with syntax highlighting!