# Laravel syntax error, unexpected 'Route' <T_STRING>

Tags: laravel

i'm using laravel framework 5.7.8.
I want to run php artisan serve in cmd but there is error.

---

### In web.php line 17:

syntax error, unexpected 'Route' (T_STRING)

---

in my web.php it looks like this :

---

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['admin']] , function();
{   Route::get('/dashboard','Admin\AdminController@dashboard'); 
    Route::get('/logout','Adminauth\AdminController@logout');
}
```

---

can someone please help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the semicolon after `function()`.

Comment: lol. silly me. thanks jonas :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [syntax error, unexpected T\_STRING php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261333/syntax-error-unexpected-t-string-php)

Answer (score 3):

As @Jonas Staudenmeir pointed out you have an extra semicolon, the code should look like

```
Route::middleware(['admin'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard','Admin\AdminController@dashboard'); 
    Route::get('/logout','Adminauth\AdminController@logout');
});
```